# vb.net code in timer loop but need to delay processing of intial step

Tags: vb.net, timer

**UPDATE** I have added a simplified version of my code. I substituted the scope read routine for a rich text box. It is now possible to see all relevant steps.

I'm developing an app which sends data to an Arduino via a serial port, and then reads data from a USB oscilloscope in the same step(s).

At low frequencies, (below 20Hz) the settling time of the oscilloscope is too slow and my loop then fails to process the data (just on the first step) but it works fine once past this initial step.

I've tried a delay (Call readDelay) which was another timer sub, but this did not work.

How can I delay the processing **of only the initial loop `(Case 5 to 50)`**, to give the USB 'scope time to catch up?

Or is my approach wrong for this?

I believe the issue here is one of ***timing*** - in just the initial Case 5 to 50 section.

The timer (Timer1) is a 3 second delay.

My code looks like this:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Public list As New ArrayList
    Dim timeLoop As Integer = 0
    Public timeBase As String = Nothing
    Public freq As Decimal
    Dim freqList() As Decimal = {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000}

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub readScope()
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(freq)
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ' timer 1 delays the loop count

        If timeLoop <= 12 Then
            freq = freqList(timeLoop)
            freq = Math.Round(freq, 2)
            Label1.Text = timeLoop
            'Label1.Text = freq
        End If

        If timeLoop >= 12 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Label1.Text = timeLoop
        End If

        Select Case freq
            Case 5 To 50
                If Not timeBase = "3" Then
                    timeBase = "3"
                    Label2.Text = timeBase
                End If
                'SerialPort1.WriteLine("f" & " " & freq)
                Thread.Sleep(1)
                'If freq <= 11 Then
                '   Call readDelay() *** need a delay here
                'End If
                Call readScope()

            Case 50 To 500
                If Not timeBase = "5" Then
                    timeBase = "5"
                    Label2.Text = timeBase
                End If
                'SerialPort1.WriteLine("f" & " " & freq)
                Call readScope()

            Case 500 To 5000
                If Not timeBase = "8" Then
                    timeBase = "8"
                    Label2.Text = timeBase
                End If
                'SerialPort1.WriteLine("f" & " " & freq)
                Call readScope()

            Case 5000 To 50000
                If Not timeBase = "11" Then
                    timeBase = "11"
                    Label2.Text = timeBase
                End If
                'SerialPort1.WriteLine("f" & " " & freq)
                Call readScope()

            Case 50000 To 1100000
                If Not timeBase = "15" Then
                    timeBase = "15"
                    Label2.Text = timeBase
                End If
                'SerialPort1.WriteLine("f" & " " & freq)
                Call readScope()
        End Select
         timeLoop = timeLoop + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        freq = freqList(0)
        'SerialPort1.WriteLine("f" & " " & freq)
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 3000
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You mention that it does not work, but you do not identify what the failure is.  If you are experiencing a read error (exception or such), you should be able to simply have a loop and exception handler to repeat until success or time out.  If you are receiving zero data, loop until data or time-out... You would need to configure your own time-out, e.g. 10 times is failure, or 1000 ms, or something along that line.

Comment: The failure is as I described it - the USB scope receives a 10Hz sine wave, but because the response time of the scope is so slow at such a low frequency, it hasn't yet accumulated sufficient data for the read (readScope) routine to return accurate data, so the 'readScope' routine occurs to soon. So basically for frequencies below 20Hz, I could do with delaying the 'readScope' routine for about 0.5 second (or so) just to give the scope sufficient time to acquire the data.

Comment: If the `readScope` method is the source of the problem, then why have you not shown us how that is implemented?

Comment: Readscope is not the source of the problem - - *timing* is the issue here. As stated, I need to be able to delay the call to the readScope sub routine. If I can do that, my problem will be solved. I've tried *Thread.Sleep()* however that *kind of* solves the but creates other problems (the following commands get queued as the timer continues to run and then several reads happen in a fast sequence following the wake up from sleep).

Comment: I'm not sure a windows form is the best place to do this...are you familiar with the concept of a "Game loop" from video games...a way to provide consistent behavior of inputs across devices...usually intentionally slowing down certain activities

Comment: I see some inconsistency here: Where is `timeloop` initialised and disposed? And why are you using it both as an event-driven counter and an array index?

Comment: What generates the Tick event? And how is that Event spawned (this may provide clues on how to generate an initial delay). All you have shown us is the event handler.

Comment: Your key variables in here are (from our perspective) undefined types. This hampers understanding of what is happening. I suspect that some code can be set prior to event handling, giving a cleaner look at what event handling does (see previous comment about understanding how it is fired in the first place). You also do not refer to the `sender` and the `event args` - these may also provide clues on how to generate an initial delay.

Comment: I have revised my original post to show a simplified version of the code. The scope read function has been replaced with a rich text box.

Comment: I know nothing useful about scopes, but does the scope signal when it is able to send accurate data, or does it just not send anything until it has data to send?

Comment: @David, it would be so helpful if it did! But sadly not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really appears you are fighting a buffering issue, not a data retrieval issue.  You should not have issues with timing when it comes to serial communications unless you are operating with too small or too large of a buffer.  Also, it is always safer to have serial reads handled through events rather than timed pulls, though, with an oscilloscope you should be able to calculate your read times based on your data rate.

Comment: @Roy Folkker - all communication with the scope is via USB. I'm not having  any issues communicating with the Arduino via serial. I have solved it now anyway.